# Get the CodingKeys key value

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, using Codable struct and CodingKeys emum,
If i have a Coordinate object, how can i get the latitude and longitude CodingKeys values, as an array ["1","2"]

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    var latitude: Bool?
    var longitude: Bool?
    var elevation: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "1"
        case longitude = "2"
        case elevation = "3"
    }
}
```

And how to get all the CodingKeys values, only for the variables that are true ?
for example if longitude and elevation are set to true, I will get the array ["2,"3"]

Comment: I'm not clear wha the question is here. Given your literal question, the answer is `var values: [String] { if longitude == true && elevation == true { return ["2", "3"]} else { return [] } }` but I suspect this isn't quite what you mean. What problem are you solving where you need `Bool?`. What type is this that just says "yes/no/undetermined" for three axes?

Comment: Why are your properties of type Bool, shouldn't they all be Double?

Comment: So in your code you have return ["2", "3"] it's not what I want. I want to get the values from the enum

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean because in your question you say you want an array of strings. Also it looks like you are asking 2 (unclear) questions when you should ask only one (clear) question.

Answer (score 1):

`CaseIterable` will be helpful

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    var latitude: Bool?
    var longitude: Bool?
    var elevation: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case latitude = "1"
        case longitude = "2"
        case elevation = "3"
    }

    var allKeys: [String] {
        CodingKeys.allCases.map { $0.stringValue }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, something like this might work:

```
let myCoordinates = Coordinate(latitude: true, longitude: false, elevation: true)
var myArray: [String] = []
if myCoordinates.latitude ?? false {
    myArray.append("1")
}
if myCoordinates.longitude ?? false {
    myArray.append("2")
}
if myCoordinates.elevation ?? false {
    myArray.append("3")
}
```

Also, thanks! I didn’t know Codable existed and now I think I might use it on my project!

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how `Codable` is used to either decode or encode data

Comment: Yes, I was assuming this was after the data was decoded into this format. If you wanted it encoded, you would not do this.